# Run command and send key event. Go

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I trying to execute a command, but that command is waiting for user confirmation something like: `Do you want to continue? (Y/n)` So the user should type `y` and press enter... but I want to do this by the user, that you run de command and automatically it send `y` and press enter to the console app. (The solution should be cross-platform)

I was trying this:

```golang
func getShell() string {
    os := runtime.GOOS
    if os == "windows" {
        return "powershell"
    }

    return "bash"
}

func OutLive(command string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(getShell(), "-c", command)

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        m := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(m)
    }

    cmd.Wait()
}

func main() {
    shell.OutLive(`stencil download`)
}
```

I did this to try that the user press `y` and `Enter` but it didn't work, because the program ends automatically when the question of (y/n) shows up and it doesn't allow me to prompt any information.

I'm looking for one of these solutions:

- Run the command and send `y` and press `enter` automatically without user action.
- Execute the command and wait for that user to enter the information himself.

Comment: The application configured the command to read from the null device.  Use the following to get input from the parent application's stdin: `cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin`